# why overfitting gives a bad hypothesis function

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, linear-regression

In linear or logistic regression if we find a hypothesis function which fits the training set perfectly then it should be a good thing because in that case we have used 100 % of the information given to predict new information.
While it is called to be overfitting and said to be bad thing.
By making the hypothesis function simpler we may be actually increasing the noise instead of decreasing it.
Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overfitting occurs when you try "too hard" to make the examples in the training set fit the classification rule.

It is considered bad thing for 2 reasons main reasons:

1. The data might have **noise**. Trying too hard to classify 100% of the examples correctly, will make the noise count, and give you a bad rule while ignoring this noise - would *usually* be much better.
2. Remember that the classified training set is just a sample of the real data. This solution is usually more complex than what you would have got if you tolerated a few wrongly classified samples. According to [**Occam's Razor**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor), you should prefer the simpler solution, so ignoring some of the samples, will be better,

**Example**:

According to Occam's razor, you should tolerate the misclassified sample, and assume it is noise or insignificant, and adopt the simple solution (green line) in this data set:
[image]

Comment: I do accept the concept of noise but if we take noise in consideration we dont know that by make it fit a little badly we are decreasing noise or increasing it

Comment: @ShubhamSharma: This is exactly where Occam's razor comes in. If the solution is simpler while you assume a few examples are noise - it is probably the case. *Usually* the probability of having a few noisy examples is much higher then the probability of having all the examples classified correctly.

Comment: Yeah that it the thing we are assuming is "probability of having a few noisy examples is much higher then the probability of having all the examples classified correctly" i know this is little troubling but can you tell me why do we assume this

Comment: @ShubhamSharma: We do not assume this. This is the general case (statistically), "No noise" - is an assumption. Why? This are some basics of probability, but assume there is a chance `p>0` that one classification or features in the training set is wrong (this is usually the case, statistically), then the chance of having all `n` samples classified correctly is `(1-p)^n`. It is easy to see that for 5% error (`p=0.05`), [after only 14 examples, the probability of having all samples classified correctly is less then 50%](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.95^n+%3D+0.5)

Answer (score 2):

Because you actually didn't "learn" anything from your training set, you've just fitted to your data.

Imagine, you have a one-dimensional regression

```
x_1 -> y_1 
...  
x_n -> y_1
```

The function, defined this way

```
         y_n, if x = x_n
  f(x)=     
         0, otherwise
```

will give you perfect fit, but it's actually useless.

Hope, this helped a bit:)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your regression accounts for *all* source of deviation in your data, then you might argue that your regression perfectly fits the data.  However, if you know all (and I mean *all*) of the influences in your system, then you probably don't need a regression.  You likely have an analytic solution that perfectly predicts new information.

In actuality, the information you possess will fall short of this perfect level.  Noise (measurement error, partial observability, etc) will cause deviation in your data.  In response, a regression (or other fitting mechanism) should seek the general trend of the data while minimizing the influence of noise.

Comment: I do accept the concept of noise but if we take noise in consideration we dont know that by make it fit a little badly we are decreasing noise or increasing it

Comment: I think it's a good idea to keep residual (i.e. fitting error) conceptually apart from "noise".  Noise presumably exists in the system prior to your fit, and noise is not something that your approximation should inject into the system.  (That implies feedback, another thing entirely). The residuals don't come into play until after the fit effort.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the statement is not quite correct as written.  It is perfectly fine to match 100% of your data if your hypothesis function is linear.  Every continuous nonlinear function may be approximated locally by a linear function which gives important information on it's local behavior.

It is also fine to match 100 points of data to a quadratic curve if that data matches 100%.  You can have high confidence that you are not overfitting your data, since the data consistently shows quadratic behavior.

However, one can always get 100% fit by using a polynomial function of high enough degree.  Even without the noise that others have pointed out, though, you shouldn't assume your data has some high degree polynomial behavior without having some kind of theoretical or experimental confirmation of that hypothesis.  Two good indicators that polynomial behavior is indicated are:

- You have some theoretical reason for expecting the data to grow as x^n in one of the directional limits.
- You have data that has been supporting a fixed degree polynomial fit as more and more data has been collected.

Notice, though, that even though **exponential and reciprocal** relationships may have data that fits a polynomial of high enough degree, they don't tend to obey eith of the two conditions above.

The point is that your data fit needs to be useful to prediction.  You always know that a linear fit will give information locally, but that information becomes more useful the more points are fit.  Even if there are only two points and noise, a linear fit still gives the best theoretical look at the data collected so far, and establishes the first expectations of the data.  Beyond that, though, using a quadratic fit for three points or a cubic fit for four is not validly giving more information, as it assumes both local and asymptotic behavior information with the addition of one point.  You need justification for your hypothesis function.  That justification can come from more points or from theory.

(A third reason that sometimes comes up is

- You have theoretical and experimental reason to believe that error and noise do not contribute more than some bounds, and you can take a polynomial hypothesis to look at local derivatives and the behavior needed to match the data.

This is typically used in understanding data to build theoretical models without having a good starting point for theory.  You should still strive to use the smallest polynomial degree possible, and look to substitute out patterns in the coefficients with what they may indicate (reciprocal, exponential, gaussian, etc.) in infinite series.)

Answer (score 0):

Try imagining it this way. You have a function from which you pick `n` different values to represent a sample / training set:

```
y(n) = x(n), n is element of [0, 1]
```

But, since you want to build a robust model, you want to add a little noise to your training set, so you actually add a little noise when generating the data:

```
data(n) = y(n) + noise(n) = x(n) + u(n)
```

where by `u(n)` I marked a uniform random noise with a mean 0 and standard deviation 1: `U(0,1)`. Quite simply, it's a noise signal which is most probable to take an value `0`, and less likely to take a value farther it is from `0`.

And then you draw, let's say, 10 points to be your training set. If there was no noise, they would all be lying on a line `y = x`. Since there was noise, the lowest degree of polynomial function that can represent them is probably of 10-th order, a function like: `y = a_10 * x^10 + a_9 * x^9 + ... + a_1 * x + a_0`.

If you consider, by just using an *estimation* of the information from the training set, you would probably get a simpler function than the 10-th order polynomial function, and it would have been closer to the real function.

Consider further that your real function can have values outside the `[0, 1]` interval but for some reason the samples for the training set could only be collected from this interval. Now, a simple estimation would probably act *significantly better* outside the interval of the training set, while if we were to fit the training set perfectly, we would get an *overfitted* function that meandered with lots of ups and downs all over :)

Comment: Nice explanation thanks,Now consider a case when the noise is not present and this is a not so rare case then what about our algorithm.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma algorithm has little to do with the training sample... and noise is *always* present. if by nothing else, then, if you are measuring live data (somehow correctly), there will still be a little error due to floating point data representation

Answer (score 0):

Overfitting is termed as bad due to the bais it has to the true solution. The solution which is overfit is 100% fitting to the training data which is used but with any small data point addition the model will change drastically. This is called variance of the model. Hence the bais-variance tradeoff where we try to have a balance between both the factors so that, the model does not change drastically on small data changes but also reasonably properly predicts the output.